# How to error handle in cypress for element not found

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

The below block successfully executes when tr is found, but sometimes it will be empty and no tr. How to handle the exception if tr not found?

```
  cy.get('tbody.ant-table-tbody tr').then((rows) => {
      // success
  });
```

There is no catch block chained here.

Answer (score 3):

There is an add-on package [cypress-if](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if) written by former lead engineer at Cypress that addressed this problem.

The syntax is simple, just chain `.if()` and eveything after it only runs if the element is found.

```js
cy.get('tbody.ant-table-tbody tr')
  .if()                               // checks for 4 seconds
  .then((rows) => {
      // success
  })
  .else()
  .then(() => {
    //no rows
  })
  .finally(() => {
    // either way
  })
```

It will suppress the error that usually occurs when the element is missing.

It will use Cypress retry for asynchronous element loading, will will not happen if you use the `jQuery` method.

**Don't do this if rows are fetched asynchronously**

```js
cy.get('tbody.ant-table-tbody').then(($parent) => {

  // This will evaluate immediately and fail if the row is still loading
  if ($parent.find('tr').length) { 
    ...
```

---

#### But cypress-if is broken in Cypress v12

Cypress v12 split cypress commands into "commands" and "queries" (`cy.get()` is a query) and blocked overwriting of queries. This breaks a whole lot of prior code, including `cypress-if`.

Expect the change to be reversed before long.

Please see issue [Can we please overwrite query commands #25078](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25078)

Answer (score 1):

`cy.get()` will always fail if it cannot find the element (unless you run `cy.get('foo').should('not.exist')`, but that can't be used in combination with if/else.)

You can instead use JQuery in combination with Cypress to check for an element's existence without failing a test. In this case, we'll yield the result from the parent element, and search it with JQuery.

```js
cy.get('tbody.ant-table-tbody').then(($parent) => {
  if ($parent.find('tr').length) { // check if the length is > 0
    // Code to run if tr is found
  } else {
    // Code to run if tr is not found
  }
});
```

All of that being said, I would push back on needing to use something like this. Tests should be deterministic, and you should know before the test runs if `tr` exists or not. Consider the ways that you can pre-determine before the test runs (maybe seeding a database, or intercepting a network request). Also consider, what happens if `tr` never exists -- that functionality is never being tested. Or, if `tr` always exists, then the functionality of when it doesn't exist is never being tested.